# golang: google wire: Как упростить поддержку кода?

Tags: golang, di

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с di google wire

wire.go

```
//go:build wireinject
// +build wireinject

package di

//go:generate wire ./...

import (
    "github.com/3110Y/profile/internal/application/service"
    "github.com/3110Y/profile/internal/application/validator"
    "github.com/3110Y/profile/internal/infrastructure/database"
    "github.com/3110Y/profile/internal/infrastructure/repository"
    "github.com/3110Y/profile/internal/presentation/rpc"
    "github.com/google/wire"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

type DI struct {
    ProfileService    *service.ProfileService
    ProfileValidator  *validator.ProfileValidator
    ProfileRepository *repository.ProfileRepository
    ProfileRPC        *rpc.ProfileRPC
    DB                *sqlx.DB
}

func NewDI(
    profileService *service.ProfileService,
    profileValidator *validator.ProfileValidator,
    profileRepository *repository.ProfileRepository,
    profileRPC *rpc.ProfileRPC,
    DB *sqlx.DB,
) *DI {
    return &DI{
        ProfileService:    profileService,
        ProfileValidator:  profileValidator,
        ProfileRepository: profileRepository,
        ProfileRPC:        profileRPC,
        DB:                DB,
    }
}

func InitializeDI() (*DI, error) {
    wire.Build(
        NewDI,
        wire.Bind(new(service.ProfileRepositoryInterface), new(*repository.ProfileRepository)),
        wire.Bind(new(service.PasswordServiceInterface), new(*service.PasswordService)),
        wire.Bind(new(rpc.ServiceProfileInterface), new(*service.ProfileService)),
        service.NewPasswordService,
        service.NewProfileService,
        validator.NewProfileValidator,
        repository.NewProfileRepository,
        rpc.NewProfileRPC,
        database.NewConnect,
    )
    return &DI{}, nil
}
```

Можно обойтись без struct Di?